# sql variable on select statement

Tags: sql, variables

Trying to create a result set that has balance due, interest charge, total due and a payment plan. They way I'm coding it appears to work but it seems very inelegant. Is there a way to utilize variables to make the code more clear?

```
SELECT 
    CustFName, CustLName, CustPhone, 
    SUM(InvoiceAmount - PaymentAmount) AS BalanceDue,
    SUM(InvoiceAmount - PaymentAmount)*.195 AS InterestCharge,
    SUM(InvoiceAmount - PaymentAmount) + SUM(InvoiceAmount - PaymentAmount) *.195 AS TotalDue,
    (SUM(InvoiceAmount - PaymentAmount) + SUM(InvoiceAmount - PaymentAmount) *.195)/4 AS PaymentPlan
FROM 
    Customer 
JOIN 
    Vehicle ON Customer.CustomerID = Vehicle.CustomerID
JOIN 
    Invoice ON Vehicle.VehicleID = Invoice.VehicleID
WHERE 
    InvoiceAmount - PaymentAmount > 400
GROUP BY 
    CustFName, CustLName, CustPhone
```

Comment: That doesn't look like `inelegant`: a subjective term anyway. This seems well laid out, if it works fine

Comment: ok thank you! I'm a novice and wasn't sure if there was a better approach.

Comment: What database system you're using?

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @p FLOAT
SET @p = 0.195
SELECT CustFName, CustLName, CustPhone, SUM(InvoiceAmount - PaymentAmount) AS BalanceDue,
    SUM(InvoiceAmount - PaymentAmount)*@p AS InterestCharge,
    SUM(InvoiceAmount - PaymentAmount) + SUM(InvoiceAmount - PaymentAmount) *@p AS TotalDue,
    (SUM(InvoiceAmount - PaymentAmount) + SUM(InvoiceAmount - PaymentAmount) *@p)/4 AS PaymentPlan

FROM Customer JOIN Vehicle
    ON Customer.CustomerID = Vehicle.CustomerID
    JOIN Invoice
    ON Vehicle.VehicleID = Invoice.VehicleID

WHERE InvoiceAmount - PaymentAmount > 400

GROUP BY CustFName, CustLName, CustPhone
```

Comment: You can extract variables to avoid repeating the hard coded constants

Answer (score 0):

Use a virtual table. Other than that, nicely done.  :-)

```
SELECT 
    CustFName, CustLName, CustPhone, 
    BalanceDue,
    BalanceDue * Factor AS InterestCharge,
    BalanceDue + BalanceDue * Factor AS TotalDue,
    (BalanceDue + BalanceDue * Factor)/4 AS PaymentPlan
from (
        SELECT 
            CustFName, CustLName, CustPhone, 0.195 as Factor
            SUM(InvoiceAmount - PaymentAmount) AS BalanceDue
        FROM 
            Customer 
        JOIN 
            Vehicle ON Customer.CustomerID = Vehicle.CustomerID
        JOIN 
            Invoice ON Vehicle.VehicleID = Invoice.VehicleID
        WHERE 
            InvoiceAmount - PaymentAmount > 400
        GROUP BY 
            CustFName, CustLName, CustPhone
) as A;
```